# When I add Spring batch configuration I get error

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-batch

In my project I use multiple schema (multiple dataSource)

When I add Spring batch configuration I get error:`No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 5`

but when I remove spring batch configuration the error is removed.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(MyDataSourceClassConfig.class)
public class TestBatchJobConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
   ....


}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you also facing same problem, you need to verify two point.

First you have to do not create a bean transaction named transactionManager (this default one used by spring batch)

Second you need to override getTransactionManager to specify which transactionManager you want to use and which dataSource you want to use

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myPersonalTransactionManager")
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;


@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    return transactionManager;
}
@Override
@Autowired
public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("thirdDataSource") DataSource batchDataSource) {
    super.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
}
```